# Google BigQuery Write Storage API quota CreateWriteStream requests per minute

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, streaming

I'm trying to build a scalable ETL process that writes on different tables of BigQuery. This process is triggered by PubSub, so n Cloud Functions are instantiated (by default all of them are in us-central1) to acchieve the goal. I'm using the BigQuery Storage Write API, python client, to stream the data into BigQuery.

Usually when more than 100 CFs are instantiated I'm getting the following resumed error message:

```json
429 Exceeds quota limit subject: ?metric=bigquerystorage.googleapis.com/write/create_stream_requests&limit=CreateWriteStreamRequestsPerMinutePerProject&qs_error_code=INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS description: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'CreateWriteStream requests' and limit 'CreateWriteStream requests per minute' of service 'bigquerystorage.googleapis.com'...
```

Figuring out the quota limits here at docs, I'm wondering why I'm getting this error? Shouldn't it be limited by 10k of concurrent connections?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#write-api-limits

> Your project can operate on 10,000 concurrent connections in the us
> and eu multi-regions, and 100 in other regions.

Or by region they mean to say n < 10k that the job has this limit when splited inside, for example, of the 'us' region, like us-central1, us-central2, and so on?

[CreateWriteStream limits, showing 10k but accusing quota limit when +100 concurrency connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4dXN.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are some quotas that might be at play here:

- The quota on concurrent connections is 10K in us/eu multi-region and 100 in a single region.
- There is a 3GB/s throughput quota on the project (this can be upscaled upon request).
- There is a 50K per 4 hours quota on Connection rates and CreateWriteStream rates.
- There is a limit on the number of active Streams you can open to a given table, currently the limit is 10K (you can use FinalizeWriteStream to get these collected sooner).

Note that these might change in the future.

Comment: Hi Stephanie Wang, thanks for trying to help! At this case I have mentioned, each Cloud Function (100 instances at maximum) opens one connection to a table on BigQuery, hosted on us multi-region, process the data and finalizes the stream.

That said, reading your answer and looking at the image attached where I noticed that quote limit error was a CreateWriteStream, I still couldn't figure out what quote limit It was exceeding.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I just checked this error `CreateWriteStreamRequestsPerMinutePerProject` and it's been deprecated. Can you upgrade to using v1 client and the quota for CreateWriteStream is 50K requests over 4 hour period.